# Java class Circuit for a light switch

Tags: java

I am not sure how to even start this simple program. I am over thinking this and I haven't really learned how to do something like this. This is the description:

Simulate a circuit for controlling a hallway light that has switches at both ends of the hallway.
Each switch can be up or down, and the light can be on or off. Toggling either switch turns the light on or off. I have these methods but unsure about how to use them.

```
public int getFirstSwitchState() (0 for down "off", 1 for up "on")

public int getSecondSwitchState() (0 for down "off", 1 for up "on")

public int getLightState() (0 for "off", 1 for "on")

public void toggleFirstSwitch()

public void toggleSecondSwitch()

public int getSwitchState(int switch)

public void toggleSwitch(int switch)
```

Then have a TestCircuit class that tests all switch combinations, printing out actual and expected states for the switches and light

Comment: There isn't much help we can give you without giving the entire solution. 1. You'll want a class variable for the first and second switch state; an array may work best 2. You may be interested in the exclusive or for one of the methods.

Comment: @Zachary I am completely new to java, and teaching my self. How would I go about getFirstSwitchState? Should i set a variable equal 0 or..

Comment: [Start with the basics.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html)

Comment: You might want to a try a discussion forum website for Java programmers (StackOverflow is not a forum) - for example, https://javaranch.com/

Answer (score -1):

This is one case where the object-oriented paradigm can be helpful.  Remember, one way to use objects is to represent something in the real world.  I would start by defining an object (a class) to represent a circuit.  A circuit can have two states: current flowing and current not flowing.  Switches modify that state.

Start with this and see if you can figure out where the methods you posted should fit and what they should do.  I will update my answer if you work out the solution.

```
public class Circuit {
    private int currentFlowing;
}
```

Comment: so would I do something like this public Switch() { switchState = 0; }
 public Switch(int state) {
  switchState = state;
 }

 public int getSwitchState() {
  return switchState;
 }

Comment: Remember that you need to track the state for each switch, so you either need a variable for each switch or you need to define a class to represent a switch and have separate instances of it for each one.  Also, remember the requirement that both switches control the light (i.e. whether current is flowing).